# How can I check whether a string is an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a string `"1234223"` and I want to check whether the value is an integer/number.

How can I do that in one line?

I have tried

```
1 =~ /^\d+$/
 => nil

"1a" =~ /^\d+$/
 => nil
```

Both line are returning nil.

Comment: For me your solution works fine, it is just that in the first case you are running the regexp on an int and not a string. Try to change the first line to "1" =~ /^\d+$/

Comment: Do you want _any_ integer, or an integer that is within the range of a built-in numeric type? If the former use regex, if the later use type conversion with `rescue`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're attempting to keep similar semantics to the original post, use either of the following:

```
"1234223" =~ /\A\d+\z/ ? true : false
#=> true

!!("1234223" =~ /\A\d+\z/)
#=> true
```

A more idiomatic construction using Ruby 2.4's new [Regexp#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F) method to return a Boolean result will also do the same thing, while also looking a bit cleaner too. For example:

```
"1234223".match? /\A\d+\z/
#=> true
```

Comment: Nice, but what about negative numbers?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Not part of the OP's corpus. Simple questions get simple answers.

Comment: There might not be a negative number in the examples, but the headline question asks about _integers_, not _whole numbers_ (or _unsigned integers_).

Answer (score 21):

Use `Integer("123") rescue nil`.

Comment: best answer in my opinion. simple. i don't know why people prefer using complex regex...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex`

```
"123".match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true
```

It will also check for `decimals`.

Comment: Nice, but why the `\.`?  The question is about integers, not decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
"1234223".tap{|s| break s.empty? || s =~ /\D/}.!
```